# Equivariant Whitney approximation

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am wondering if there is a reference for the following:

Let $G$ be a finite group, and suppose that $f\colon M\rightarrow N$ is a continuous and $G$-equivariant map. Here $M$ and $N$ are finite dimensional $G$-manifolds, where $M$ possibly has boundary (I only care when $M$ is compact if that helps). Suppose also that $A\subset M$ is a closed $G$-invariant subset of $M$ on which $f$ is smooth, in that there exists an open neighborhood $U\subset M$ containing $A$ and a smooth equivariant function $h\colon U\rightarrow N$ such that $h\rvert_A=f\rvert_A$. Is it true that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a smooth equivariant map $f_\epsilon\colon M\rightarrow N$ such that

1. $\lvert f_\epsilon(x)-f(x)\rvert<\epsilon$ for all $x\in M$ and
2. $f_\epsilon\rvert_A=f\rvert_A$?

Comment: TeX note: `\mid` is meant for a binary relation, like $2 \mid 6$ `2 \mid 6`.  If you want an abstract vertical line, then `\vert` does the job; and it comes in `\lvert` and `\rvert` variants, depending on whether it goes on the left ("mathopen") or on the right ("mathclose").  Thus, compare $h\mid_A = f\mid_A$ `h\mid_A = f\mid_A` to $h\rvert_A = f\rvert_A$ `h\rvert_A = f\rvert_A`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: The answer of the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136749/equivariant-smooth-map?rq=1 seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Corollary 1.12 in

*Wasserman, A. G.*, [**Equivariant differential topology**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(69)90005-6), Topology 8, 127-150 (1969). [ZBL0215.24702](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0215.24702).

The proof is essentially the same as the one given by Peter Michor in [his answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/136765/8103) to [the question linked in the comments by Nick L](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136749/8103).

**Added later:** In fact the above reference does not treat the relative case. A textbook reference for the result in the generality asked for is Theorem 4.2 in Chapter VI of

*Bredon, Glen E.*, Introduction to compact transformation groups, Pure and Applied Mathematics, 46. New York-London: Academic Press. XIII,459 p. $ 21.00 (1972). [ZBL0246.57017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0246.57017).